# spark giving incorrect output for some value and correct output for some value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Apache spark in spark-shell when I perform SQL query I get different outputs

I have the spark cluster having one master and one slave node. on the master, there is one worker and on the slave node, there is one worker. so I have total two worker nodes.

now when I am persisting some data and then performing some filters onto that persisted data each time I got two different outputs but these two different outputs are distinct they are not changing every time, in short, i am getting two different output for one SQL query.

I have the MySQL database on both master and slave node in which I have a table having 50000 records into it on the slave and on master also there are 50000 records this 50k + 50k records are different not the same.

so when I am querying the result becomes different. here is my code that I am trying and also a screenshot of output.

```
spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=C:\spark-warehouse --master spark://192.168.0.31:7077

val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options( Map("url" ->  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmanalytics?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&user=root&password=root", "dbtable" -> "cmanalytics.demo_call", "fetchSize" -> "1000", "partitionColumn" -> "newpartition", "lowerBound" -> "0", "upperBound" -> "4", "numPartitions" -> "4")).load()

jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("demo_call")

val sqlDF = sql("select * from demo_call").persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

sqlDF.show()

val d = sqlDF.filter(sqlDF("campaign_id")===141).groupBy("classification_id").count

d.count
```

and the screenshot of output is

[image]

can any one help to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably aware, Spark does lazy evaluation and your problem here is simply that you assume that `show` will force evaluation of your `DataFrame`, but that assumption is wrong. `show` has no such guarantees and may very well only evaluate a subset of rows. To force evaluation of the entire `DataFrame` you would need to call an action like, say, `count` first.

```
val sqlDF = sql("sql("select count(*) from demo_call where classification_id = 141").persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)").persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

sqlDF.count // to force evaluation
```

Every call to `show` should give you the same result from now on

Comment: it means datafrme.show not evaluating the entire data frame right?

Comment: Thanks, but what I had done that on both machines the data that i had in that machines, some data were missing so i had put the data on both side same and try to do the same thing and it works.